# Simulate merging of two ssDNA together

Tags: biochemistry, dna, bioinformatics, computational-model

I have two .pdb files with two ssDNAs, which should form some specific shape when closed together. Is it possible to model/simulate this merging somehow?

I would preferably like to have a program that would take both .pdb files as input and return .pdb file of the combined molecule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structures are relatively small (< 4 nt), you can use ***Chem3D*** (from PerkinElmer ChemOffice software): Load both of the PDB files and run an MM2 minimization task.
For more complex structures ***GROMACS*** or similar molecular dynamics tools are used.